# Recreation of mapping elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, bigdata

[logstash config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VK2Na.png)I have created my index on elasticsearch and through kibana as well and have uploaded data. Now i want to change the mapping for the index and change some fields to not analyzed .Below is my mapping which i want to replace from existing one . But when i run below command it gives me error

> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_already_exists_exception","reason":"already
>   exists","index":"rettrmt"}],"type":"index_already_exists_exception","reason":"already
>   exists","index":"rettrmt"},"status":400}

Kindly help to get it close.

```
curl -XPUT 'http://10.56.139.61:9200/rettrmt' -d '{
  "rettrmt": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "RETTRMT": {
        "properties": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "@version": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "acid": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "actor_id": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "actor_type": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "channel_id": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "circle": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "cr_dr_indicator": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "host": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "message": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "orig_input_amt": {
            "type": "double"
          },
          "path": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "r_cre_id": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "sub_use_case": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "tran_amt": {
            "type": "double"
          },
          "tran_id": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "tran_particulars": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "tran_particulars_2": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "tran_remarks": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "tran_sub_type": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "tran_timestamp": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "tran_type": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "type": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "use_case": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "creation_date": "1457331693603",
        "uuid": "2bR0yOQtSqqVUb8lVE2dUA",
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "version": {
          "created": "2000099"
        }
      }
    },
    "warmers": {}
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 11):

You first need to delete your index and then recreate it with the proper mapping. Here you're getting an error `index_already_exists_exception` because you try to create an index while the older index still exists, hence the conflict.

Run this first:

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://10.56.139.61:9200/rettrmt'
```

And then you can run your command again. Note that this will erase your data, so you will have to repopulate your index.

Comment: If i will delete the index it will delete the data as well Isn't it ?

Comment: However i have deleted index so it deleted the data as well and then run my command again to change mapping. it just put the mapping what i required but when i upload data again then over kibana again see the field as analyzed which i put not analyzed in my mapping. Any guess what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Yes, but you don't really have a choice if you want to change the mapping.

Comment: Can you share a document you're indexing and which field you think should be not_analyzed?

Comment: do you have a gmail so we could have a quick chat to discuss ? It will be really helpful .

Comment: You can join the chat here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105538/recreation-of-mapping-elastic-search

Comment: Don't have sufficient reputation to chat :(

Comment: We should be able to sort things out here easily. Please share a document you're indexing and tell us which field you think should be not_analyzed.

Comment: I didn't create any document sepratly. I just loaded the data through attached  logstash file with my question and then created index through kibana not sure where and how to find document attached to this index.

Comment: You also need to delete the index pattern in Kibana and recreate it based on your new mapping.

Comment: No luck , Its still showing the fields Analyzed. i.e. Use_case field , which is put not analyzed in my mapping but showing analyzed over kibana.

Comment: What if you delete the `.kibana` index and restart Kibana from scratch and reconfigure it?

Comment: You've deleted the .kibana index as well and relaunched Kibana?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like that ?

```
curl -XPUT 'http://10.56.139.61:9200/rettrmt/_mapping/RETTRMT' -d '
{
  "properties": {
    "actor_id": { // or whichever properties you want to add
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
    }
  }
}
```

works for me